# Template DB schema for Web Analytics workload (AWS RedShift)

Tags: postgresql, database-design, analytics, data-warehouse, amazon-redshift

Are there any existing schema template for general web analytics workload, e.g. similar to Google Analytcis, it probably have at least the following tables

1. users
2. sites
3. requests

Since I don't want to re-invent the wheel, I am looking if any existing well defined schema or good relations modeling is suitable for my need.

Any idea?

Remark: I am running on AWS RedShift, but I think most column oriented database should have similar schema.

Comment: *Thankyou* for saying you're on Redshift, not just "PostgreSQL". The number of "PostgreSQL" users lately who turn out to really be using Postgres-XC, Redshift, Greenplum, EnterpriseDB Postgres Plus, etc has been truly frustrating. I can't direct you to a schema, but I can suggest that you really need to look into schemas designed for DW/column store use, not schemas designed for regular OLTP-optimised RDBMSes.

Comment: I wish I could help more; hope someone with domain specific expertise comes along. I'd start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema but I haven't done much OLAP design.